# Handling errors in AHK and changing format of csv file

Tags: csv, automation, autohotkey

Quite often, I can't seem to find a postcode on the website I am querying for addresses, and this grinds the script to a halt and it requires me to click yes over a series of two dialog windows to carry on.

e.g.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**1. How do I get my code to ignore such error messages and carry on without halting the code and requiring user intervention i.e. just entering the postcode, leaving the data output looking something like this:**

```
Levens Hall Drive,Westcroft,MK4 4FL
,52.003,-0.798
Slatepits Croft,Olney,MK46 5EF
,52.163,-0.708
Water Eaton Road,Water Eaton,MK2 2RD
,51.99,-0.728
Southern Way,Hodge Lea,MK12 5EG
,52.054,-0.811
Saxon Street,Stantonbury,MK13 7BX
,52.067,-0.776
Tongwell Street,Brinklow,MK9 2ZQ
,52.032,-0.692
,,MK17 0FE <---------- error occurred here, ideally we would just make an entry for MK17 0FE and blank the other fields and then carry on...
Bury Street,Green Park,MK16 8EU
,52.086,-0.726
Bletcham Way,Tilbrook,MK7 7DT
,52.016,-0.689
High Street,Buckingham CP,MK18 1JL
,52.001,-0.986
Dunstable Road,Flitwick,MK45 1JB
,52,-0.496
Amway UK Ltd,Caldecotte Lake Drive,MK7 8JU
,52.003,-0.703
```

**2. My CSV output seems to be in the wrong formula whenever I open it in Excel, any idea on how I can get everything on one line?**

[image]

Code below:

```
;// Fileread, test, somefilename
fileread, AddressList, test.csv


IE := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible := true


loop, parse, AddressList, `n
{
    PostCode := A_LoopField
    IE.Navigate("http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=" PostCode)


    ToolTip, Now looking up %PostCode%


    while IE.readyState!=4 || IE.document.readyState != "complete" || IE.busy
        continue

    ; Collect results 1
    Sleep 2000

    ToolTip, ; remove tooltip

    Name_Elements       := IE.document.getElementsByClassName("name")
    Loop, 1
    {
        Addr_text       := Name_Elements[A_Index-1].innertext

        Latlon_element  := Name_Elements[A_Index-1].parentElement.getElementsByClassName("latlon")[0]
        Latlon_text     := Latlon_element.innertext

        String_Object   := StrSplit(Addr_text, "`,")
        LatLon_Object   := StrSplit(Latlon_text, "`,")

        If (Substr(Addr_text, 1, 2) = "MK")
        {
            Addr := Trim(String_Object[2]) . "," . Trim(String_Object[3]) . "," . PostCode . "," . LatLon_Object[1] . "," . LatLon_Object[2]
        }
        Else
        {
            Addr := Trim(String_Object[1]) . "," . trim(String_Object[2]) . "," . PostCode . "," . LatLon_Object[1] . "," . LatLon_Object[2]
        }

     Filename_text := Substr(PostCode, 1, 2)
StringLower Filename_text, Filename_text

FileAppend,%Addr%`n,%Filename_text%_addresslist.csv

    }
}
IE.quit()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using Try / Catch?

http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Try.htm

If you are using COM Objects you can toggle COM Errors on or off, when needed using:

http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/ComObjError.htm

Errorlevel is antiquated but can be useful:

http://ahkscript.org/docs/misc/ErrorLevel.htm

Comment: I've tried the following - http://pastebin.com/dqDDLdvD. According to my understanding using "try" before calling a function then "catch e" with nothing afterward should show nothing.

Comment: Okay now I see, enclose the function with ComObjError(false) .... code ... ComObjError(True) at the end. Report back after you test.

Comment: thanks `ComObjError(false)` works very well. How can I resolve the issue of my csv formatting?

Comment: I'd look further into using COM with Excel to write to your CSV file.